# Proving st X + st Y = st Y + (st X - 1) + 1 using Coq

Tags: coq, proof

Just like the title says, I'm looking for a way to prove `st X + st Y = st Y + (st X - 1) + 1` in Coq. I've been trying applying various combinations of `plus_comm`, `plus_assoc` and `plus_permute` but I haven't been able to make it go through. Any suggestions?

Here is the goal window:

```
3 subgoal
n : nat
m : nat
st : state
H : st Y + st X = n + m /\ beval st (BNot (BEq (AId X) (ANum 0))) = true
______________________________________(1/3)
st Y + 1 + (st X - 1) = n + m
```

Comment: Are you working with integers? In nat, it is simply not true that (X - 1) + 1 = X.

Comment: Yes I am. I think I can see how in Coq-super-strict-land (X - 1) + 1 != X. It's hard to switch over from a programming mindset where an equality test like that would work though.

Comment: Would it make a difference if I had `H : m = st X + st Y /\ beval st (BNot (BEq (AId X) (ANum 0))) = true` in the context?

Comment: It should be provable with integers without additional info. As a quick fix, `ring` and `omega` both solve `forall x y, (x + y)%Z = (y + (x - 1) + 1)%Z`. Now looking to see if there a simple way to do it manually.

Comment: I really think you're working with `nat` rather than integers, and yes the `H` you give is useful in that case. You have to massage it into a form that will allow `omega` to use the information about `st X` that is encoded in the `beval`.

Comment: The reason `(X - 1) + 1 != X` in `nat` is because `0 - 1 = 0`. In other words, for better for worse, `pred 0` is defined as `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For integers, either `ring` or `omega` should be able to solve such a goal. It can also be done manually. It helps to disable notations so that function names appear (in order use `SearchAbout` to find useful lemmas). The following is probably not the shortest possible proof, just the first I found:

```
Require Import ZArith.

Lemma simple: forall x y, (x + y)%Z = (y + (x - 1) + 1)%Z.
intros.
rewrite Z.add_sub_assoc.
replace ((y + x)%Z) with ((x + y)%Z).
Focus 2.
rewrite Z.add_comm.
reflexivity.
set (t := ((x + y)%Z)).
replace (1%Z) with (Z.succ 0).
Focus 2.
symmetry.
apply Z.one_succ.
rewrite Zminus_succ_r.
rewrite Z.add_succ_r.
rewrite <- Zminus_0_l_reverse.
rewrite <- Zplus_0_r_reverse.
rewrite Z.succ_pred.
reflexivity.
Qed.
```

Answer (score 0):

For those looking to use omega as a quick-fix, here's one way to get the goal into a form where it can be applied:

`inversion H.
  inversion H1.
  rewrite negb_true_iff in H3.
  apply beq_nat_false in H3.
  omega.`

For why omega works after we do this and not when the goal was in the original state, here is a great answer by Github user jaewooklee93:

"You don't need to think about plus_comm or similar lemmas here, because omega can solve those easy problems. Your goals are almost trivial, but the reason why omega hesistates to clear the goals is just because the minus between nat is not the same as the one we already know; 2-5=0, since there is no notion of negative in nat. So if you don't provide the fact that st X is greater than zero, omega cannot clear the goal for you. But you already have that condition in H1. Therefore, the only thing you should do is to simplify H1 and apply lemmas to H1 to make it st X<>0 .Then omega can properly work."

Comment: You are absolutely correct.  Sometimes it can improve readability to explain that X>0 to omega. `Require Import Omega.
Goal forall X Y, X>0 -> X + Y = Y + (X - 1) + 1.
intros; omega.
Qed.`